# Gargoyles (1972) - A different ending?

Tags: gargoyles-1972

In my search for [a movie or TV episode from the 1950's or early 60's with talking termite or ant-like creatures](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/194676/98028), I have read many plot summaries and re-viewed a number of vintage movies and shows with insects or other creatures.

A few nights ago it was [*Gargoyles*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068622/) (1972) which I had recalled in great detail, except for the ending sequence. The version I saw on YouTube had the two primary winged "breeding" gargoyles left to survive and reproduce in the future.

However, I recall another ending where a larger group of gargoyles flew away together as opposed to just a "breeding pair." In this case I could be mistaken, but my memory usually serves me very well even three or more decades after the fact. I recalled every segment of this film in great detail and was able to do this just before each scene. However I am a little unsure of the ending. Any who are familiar with this film, please weigh in.

Comment: I saw this as a kid on late night TV and I have the VHS and DVD of it, and I'm only aware of the ending with the 2 gargoyles escaping.

Comment: Thanks. If I get more than four or five responses like yours I'll close the question as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I completely forgot about this film.  I remember seeing it as a kid as well in the summer of '72. My recollection was that there were only two gargoyles, but it was a very long time ago.

Comment: This answer needs a link to the movie.

Answer (score 1):

I have the VHS, it was only 2 of the gargoyles that escaped.