# 1950s-60s B&W horror/sci-fi movie with news report of a "beast of seemingly gigantic proportions"

Tags: story-identification, movie

**Classic Horror/Sci-Fi News Reporter Clip of Doom**

While in pursuit of information related to my long-term burning question of an old sci-fi movie involving ants or termites

[Looking for a late 1950s to early 1960s movie or TV show with some similarities to "The Zanti Misfits"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/194676/looking-for-a-late-1950s-to-early-1960s-movie-or-tv-show-with-some-similarities)

I located a video that, to date, most closely approximates the scenes I can recall from the movie in question. Here is that video:

In the first seven seconds of the video parody linked directly above is a classic monster/horror/sci-fi movie interlude likely taken directly from an actual classic sci-fi monster movie. The brief segment features a stereotypical news broadcaster reading his emergency news bulletin of doom and gloom to the TV viewing audience.

Having viewed this numerous times now, I wonder what movie that clip was taken from.

Comment: To be clear, the video "Mad Ants Trailer" is a parody containing a mix of vintage video and still images with recent video and animations. The first seven seconds of the piece contains the original film clip from an unknown movie, the title of which is the movie Im seeking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [Teenagers from Outer Space](https://imdb.com/title/tt0053337/) (1959):

Go to about 1:07:00 in the video.

Comment: that's it. you got it

Comment: I'm curious. Did you know that one already or did you like, go hunting for "giant monsters movies" from the 50s? (Nice find, anyway!)

Comment: @Jenayah no I actually just searched for a snippet of what the guy said in the video and it gave me a subtitle site. It took me much longer to put the rest of the answer together.

Comment: Oh, nice. Went the same way at first but apparently I didn't isolate the right set of quote then :)